# Angular8 get full of HttpClient response headers

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm using HttpClient to request a `json` file. I want the file can be cached with `ETag`. But it not works. I think that The `If-None-Match` not send to the server is the reason. So I want to get The 'ETag' from response headers. But the response header not has the item in Angular, But It's truly in the HTTP response in chrome network tool. All of showing in follow images.

[image: The HttpClient response headers]

[image: The Http response headers]

*How can I get the ETag from response Header*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's similar to this : [HttpClient dont return all headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51040216/httpclient-dont-return-all-headers).

You need to setup your backend to return `Access-Control-Expose-Headers:ETag`.

Comment: Could your provide an example of a request and its response?
Do you have OPTIONS requests being sent?
Don't you receive any 304 responses when data from the server didn't changed?

Comment: Sorry to reply you late. I created an online demo, you can try it.https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b4vtlv?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

As the MDN shows the `cors` hide lots of headers, So I can't get the `ETag` in angular.

[image]

Add `Access-Control-Expose-Headers:ETag` to response header can solve this issue.